# how to access private key from eToken with jsp

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, cryptoapi, rsacryptoserviceprovider

It's my first time to here, so please forgive me at first time if I make mistake. I am new to RSA(Cryptography), My requirement is, accessing private key from eToken for decryption and store decrypted data in a file.
I want to ask here that where to find private key & how to access it via jsp page?
I am using Spring 3 and RSA.
Please share resource if any available.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the "eToken" the product described [here](http://www.roseindia.net/whatis/etoken.shtml)?  If so, it's basically a smartcard, which means you *can't* extract the private key.  The way you'd use it is to send the encrypted data to the token and have it decrypt for you.

You said you're using JSP.  Are you trying to utilize an eToken plugged into your server, or into the client's PC?  A JSP page on your server can't talk to devices plugged into the client's PC; you'd need an application running on the client (maybe a browser plugin) to do it on your behalf.

If it were possible for a website to extract the private key from a user's eToken, the eToken would be worthless as a security product.

Comment: Thanks for instant replay. It's really helpful information to me. My eToken is same as your provided link. That will be on client's PC. Also i read from an article that we can access such information from ../Win32/etoken.dll file; is it true? if it is how can do that? Can you provide me any example? I am really stuck here...

Comment: The eToken is a smartcard.  You cannot extract the private key from a smartcard.  What you *can* do is send it the data you want it to encrypt or decrypt, and it will give back the result.  That's presumably what etoken.dll is for.  But an application running on a web server cannot call DLL functions on a client PC.